# I Have Database Errors on my Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i receive the following errors when i try to login to my project, Please Help

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `_id` = '1'' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE `_id` = '1'

Filename: views/backend/header.php

Line Number: 34
```

...........................................................................
    Here is the code line for the header file
..........................

```
<?php
$name = $this->db->get_where($this->session->userdata('login_type'),
    array($this->session->userdata('login_type').'_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))
    ->row()
    ->name;
echo $name;
```

A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '_id' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `timestamp` = 1519230907 WHERE `_id` = '1' AND `id` = 'd25c0dcdaa9a86810d791b05ba53fe45b76a7bcd'

Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 243
```

Comment: ``_id` = '1'`` ?? post the code

Comment: Your query syntax is wrong but no one can offer advice until you show the code that generates the query.

Comment: SELECT * `FROM` ?

Comment: @DFriend should I send you the login details?? So you see the code?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the value of `$this->session->userdata('login_type')` be?

Comment: @DFriend I will be truthful to you.....am not a pro in codeigniter..so I will appreciate any help in fixing it, even if it involves logging into the cpanel to fix it

Comment: I can and will help. What does `$this->session->userdata('login_type')` return?

Comment: What is the name of the table you are querying?

Comment: @DFriend the ci_sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define from which table you have to fetch data, that's why this error comes. Normally we write query like

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `_id` = 1
```

you just the missed out selecting table. In codeigniter form the query should like

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where('_id', '1');
$data = $this->db->get();
```

This is the normal procedure to fetch data in codeigniter.

Comment: <?php
              $name = $this->db->get_where($this->session->userdata('login_type'), array($this->session->userdata('login_type').'_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->name;
              echo $name;
             ?>
Here is the code, how can I correct it?

Comment: Query is correct but check if any value was stored in $this->session->userdata('login_type') or not. i guess there was no value, That's Why This happens.

This query will generate SELECT * FROM $login_type WHERE $login_type_id = $login_user_id;

But if $login_type does't contain any value than it will missed ( FROM $login_type ) from the query.

Check your session value's , I Guess Your session does't containing any values.

Comment: Can I send u the cpanel login so you help fix it?? Please am not that of a pro

Comment: request sent to your skype

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add manually column and table name. And value store in variable

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('login_user_id'); 
$name = $this->db->get_where('table-name',array('column-name' => 'your-value'))->row();
$echo $name->column-name; //Using this code you can echo all your data retrieved from database
```